# Why is the proof of decidability of arithmetic (Theorem 2.1) in Hamkins & Lewis (2000) enough?

Tags: decidability, theories-of-arithmetic, infinite-time-turing-machine

Recently, I was reading the paper ["Infinite Time Turing Machines" by Hamkins & Lewis](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9808093). And one of the first theorems (Theorem 2.1) is about decidability of arithmetic.

The proof is quite short, so let me write it down here:

> **Theorem 2.1** The truth of any arithmetic statement is infinite time decidable.
>
> **Proof:** It is easy to see by an inductive argument on formulas that first order arithmetic truth is decidable: given a statement $∃nφ(n,\vec x)$, one simply directs the machine to try out all the possible values
> of $n$ and test the truth of $φ(n, \vec x)$.

What I am missing is how do we know we have checked **all** integers? Indeed, here it seems that the machine is iterating over all standard integers but not "beyond". For example, since Infinite Time Turing Machines (ITTMs) can basically only (meaningfully) run for countable times (see their theorems of section 1), it cannot not iterate over uncountable models of arithmetic and so the machine inevitably misses integers in these models.

So I'm not sure why the proof is enough. Don't we need to add a proof that all integers have been checked this way? Could it be that "decidable" here has a different meaning than when one says "the Presburger arithmetic is decidable"? Or can we limit the integer to be standard when having access to an ITTM?

Comment: This is an algorithm to tell if the statement is true in the standard model. If you're interested in whether the statement is true in all models, that can be done, but using a different algorithm - just spend infinite time search for a proof! Using any reasonable search algorithm, you'll be guaranteed to find it if it exists.